# My timepicker does not running and logcat error says BADTOKENEXCEPTION UNABLE TO ADD WINDOW

Tags: android, eclipse

this is my code on java.class
My date picker is running smoothly but in time picker which is CUSTOMIZED interval of 30 is keeping on error of unable to add window? what should i'll do? any help will be a great help....im just a newbie on android....

```
        public class loansched_accountholder extends Activity implements OnClickListener
          {
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            private Button change_date_but,proceed;
            private TextView display_txt;
            public static final int Date_dialog_id = 1;
            private int mYear;
            private int mMonth;
            private int mDay;
            private TextView txt_time = null;
            private Button btn_time = null;
             private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message"; 
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.schedule_accountholder, null);
                this.setContentView(viewToLoad );    
                change_date_but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndate);
                display_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdate); 
                proceed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.proceedsched);
                txt_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtime);
                btn_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectTime);
                change_date_but.setOnClickListener(this);
                proceed.setOnClickListener(this);
                btn_time.setOnClickListener(this);


            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            updateDisplay();
            }
            @Override
            @Deprecated
            protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);

                ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

            }

            private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };

            private void updateDisplay() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                display_txt.setText(new StringBuilder() 
                        .append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-")
                        .append(mYear));
            }
            protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
                  switch (id) {
                     case Date_dialog_id:
                            return new DatePickerDialog(MainAccountHolder.tabcontext, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                  }
                  return null;
            }

     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
          if (file_url != null){
         Toast.makeText(loansched_accountholder.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }
 }
}

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                      switch(v.getId()) {
                       case R.id.proceedsched:  
                           try{
                           new postLoan_info().execute();
                           }catch(Exception ex)
                           {
                               ex.printStackTrace();
                           }
                              break;
                           case R.id.btndate:
                               showDialog(Date_dialog_id);

                           break;
                           case R.id.buttonSelectTime:
                               try
                               {
                               CustomTimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new CustomTimePickerDialog(loansched_accountholder.this, timeSetListener, 
                                    Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR), 
                                    CustomTimePickerDialog.getRoundedMinute(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) + CustomTimePickerDialog.TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL), true);
                                        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set your appointment time");
                                        timePickerDialog.show();
                                        }catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                               break;

                      }

                }
                public static class CustomTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog{

                    public static final int TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL=30;
                    private boolean mIgnoreEvent=false;

                    public CustomTimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
                    super(context, callBack, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        super.onTimeChanged(timePicker, hourOfDay, minute);
                        if (!mIgnoreEvent){
                            minute = getRoundedMinute(minute);
                            mIgnoreEvent=true;
                            timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);
                            mIgnoreEvent=false;
                        }
                    }

                    public static  int getRoundedMinute(int minute){
                         if(minute % TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL != 0){
                            int minuteFloor = minute - (minute % TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL);
                            minute = minuteFloor + (minute == minuteFloor + 1 ? TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL : 0);
                            if (minute == 60)  minute=0;
                         }

                        return minute;
                    }
                }

             private CustomTimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener = new CustomTimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        txt_time.setText(String.format("%02d", hourOfDay) + ":" +String.format("%02d", minute));
                    }
              };


                }
```

and this is my logcat

```
02-19 12:51:27.707: W/System.err(1757): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@418d24f0 is not valid; is your activity running?
02-19 12:51:27.707: W/System.err(1757):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:559)
02-19 12:51:27.717: W/System.err(1757):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:269)
02-19 12:51:27.717: W/System.err(1757):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-19 12:51:27.717: W/System.err(1757):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
02-19 12:51:27.717: W/System.err(1757):     at com.example.mobilebankingapp.loansched_accountholder.onClick(loansched_accountholder.java:371)
02-19 12:51:27.717: W/System.err(1757):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
02-19 12:51:27.727: W/System.err(1757):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
02-19 12:51:27.727: W/System.err(1757):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-19 12:51:27.727: W/System.err(1757):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-19 12:51:27.737: W/System.err(1757):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-19 12:51:27.737: W/System.err(1757):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-19 12:51:27.737: W/System.err(1757):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 12:51:27.747: W/System.err(1757):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-19 12:51:27.747: W/System.err(1757):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-19 12:51:27.747: W/System.err(1757):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-19 12:51:27.747: W/System.err(1757):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my App thanks for those who can help me out of this...

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you are trying to change the UI from a background thread. I'm guessing `postLoan_info()` is an `AsyncTask` that does UI modification. Fix that and you should be good.

Comment: thanks...but postLoan_info() is too many line of codes so i didn't add  it...but it does really affects even though i ddin't click the button for posloan_info()????

Comment: how to fix it? same problem here